# Best way to handle mixed synchronous and asynchronous errors in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, error-handling, braintree

Using NodeJS 10.13.0, ExpressJS 4.16.4...
Got a controller handling a route that looks like this:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import braintree from 'braintree';
import config from '../../server.config';

export function index(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
  if(!config.braintree) throw new Error('Braintree configuration missing.');
  const gateway: any = braintree.connect(config.braintree); // synchronous
  return gateway.clientToken.generate({})
    .then(response => res.send(response.clientToken))
    .catch(next) // operational error unless config.braintree was changed
}
```

Reading the [ExpressJS docs on error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html), I'm wondering if I'm following best practices - throwing an Error for the synchronous portion and passing the error to next() in the catch for the asynchronous portion.

Any recommendations for improvement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that promises are in use, both synchronous and asynchronous errors can be consistently handled with `async` function:

```
export async function index(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  try {
    if(!config.braintree)
      throw new Error('Braintree configuration missing.');

    const gateway: any = braintree.connect(config.braintree);
    const response = await gateway.clientToken.generate({})
    res.send(response.clientToken);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
}
```

Since Express doesn't support promises, `async` function body should be wrapped with `try..catch`. Considering that `try..catch` is common for all `async` middleware functions, it could be moved to a helper:

```
const asyncMiddleware = (middleware: RequestHandler) => async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    await middleware(req, res, next);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
};
```

Which is used like:

```
export const index = asyncMiddleware(async (...) => {...});
```

Comment: Thanks! If you remove ": void" from the function above (since it now returns a promise), I'll mark your reply as the correct answer.

Comment: Sure, `void` was pasted.

Comment: Seems this approach is a good way to prep for ExpressJS 5.0 when promises will be supported.

Comment: I wouldn't expect 5 in production any time soon but yes, that's the way to do that. You can remove `asyncMiddleware(...)` in 5 then.